# internet explorer does not always open browser.navigate

Tags: vba, internet-explorer-11

```
Private Sub Command89_Click()
Dim oBrowser As Object
Dim time1, time2
Dim htmlButton
Dim addressInput As HTMLInputElement
Dim err_count As Integer
Dim y As Integer
On Error GoTo Err_Clear
If TempVars!debug_mode = True Then
 SendToLogFile ("AFter error clear but before navigation = " & Me.network)
End If
```

***I get to here as per my log file!***

```
 sURL = "http://permis.telusquebec.com/index.php"
'Set oBrowser = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
Set oBrowser = GetObject("new:{D5E8041D-920F-45e9-B8FB-B1DEB82C6E5E}")
 If TempVars!debug_mode = True Then
     SendToLogFile ("Entering new record create section for network = " & Me.network)
  End If

 oBrowser.Silent = True
 'oBrowser.timeout = 60
 oBrowser.navigate sURL
 oBrowser.Visible = True

 ' Wait till the Browser is loaded
Do While oBrowser.Busy Or oBrowser.ReadyState <> 4
    DoEvents
    Debug.Print oBrowser.ReadyState
Loop

If TempVars!debug_mode = True Then
    SendToLogFile ("Browser should have opened for network = " & Me.network)
End If
***Never make it to here!***
```

This is an intermittent problem, sometimes it works other times it doesn't, but the thing is 
this SAME code run perfectly on 6 other computers.IE opens every time! This computer was upgraded to windows 10 2 months ago but had the same problem with windows 7 for 6 months before that. I thought upgrading would fix the problem but it didn't. Can't figure out what would cause and intermittent problem,except some personal settings. I'm stumped.
   All computers are now on windows 10 with a company image, so we are all the same!

Pete

Comment: Could you add breakpoints in your code to see if there's any error and which line does the error point to? Is the website in your code internal? I can't open it on my side. Besides, if I use `Set oBrowser = GetObject("new:{D5E8041D-920F-45e9-B8FB-B1DEB82C6E5E}")`, it will throw error "Automation Error; Unspecified Error". It works well with `Set oBrowser = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")`, you could try to use this.

Comment: If I try to use the createobject way instead of getobject way the code doesn`t work at all and I get 462 errors!  I`ve placed traps all along the code to capture all errors to a log file and when it gets to oBrowser.navigate sURL , nothing happens. ( occasionally and on this computer only)

Comment: If the issue happens occasionally, I think it might be related with the network. Maybe the network of that computer is not stable. You could break at just that line `oBrowser.navigate sURL` to see if you can catch any error. If it stops at that line, I think there must throw some error. The specific error message can help to understand the cause of the issue.

Comment: I've added a break and an  on error just before and after to be sure I WHen it gets to  oBrowser.navigate sURL it just stops! Its not the network because we all use the same network at work and it does it at his home network as well. Really odd!

Comment: Might be some issue with the Excel file or the Office. There's some one meeting similar issue and get it repaired by repairing Excel file and installing updates of Office. You could refer to the [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39964472/excel-vba-debugger-stops-without-error-or-warning) and try the resolution in it.